# maven vs docker based apps in spring-cloud-dataflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

In spring cloud dataflow (scdf) applications can be based on [maven or docker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.9.2/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-stream-apps).

I do understand the docker way. It loads an image from the registry and deploys it as a pod on kubernetes. But how does this work with maven, when it just gets a jar? Is scdf somehow building a docker image itself?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Dataflow can deploy to other platforms besides Kubernetes. Notably, CloudFoundry, and localhost, neither uses docker.

Comment: Does this mean I must use docker for kubernetes?

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, you may want to take a look at something like Tanzu Application Platform which automates the build during deployment.